# How do I focus light or how do I only draw certain circular parts of the window in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, fill, clip, pygame-surface

For this, if you're familiar with it, think the dark mode in the boo levels in Super Mario Maker 2. I'm trying to create a circular spotlight around the character that will also make anything within the circles range visible (eg part of the floor being stood on, an enemy or anything else from the scene). My plan to do that is to first draw the circle/spotlight, then the scene and then the character. Then I want anything not highlighted by the spotlight to be blacked out.

So my question is:

Does anybody know how to fill the entire screen with the exception of what's within the circle?

Answer (score 8):

I suggest a solution, which combines a clipping region [`pygame.Surface.set_clip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_clip) and drawing a black rectangle with a circular transparent area in the center.

Define a radius and create a square [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey) with twice the radius.

```py
radius = 50
cover_surf = pygame.Surface((radius*2, radius*2))
```

Set a white color key which identifies the transparent color ([`set_colorkey`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey)) a nd draw a white (transparent) circle on the surface:

```py
cover_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
pygame.draw.circle(cover_surf, (255, 255, 255), (radius, radius), radius)
```

Define the center of the circular region which you want to see (in the following `clip_center`).
In the main application loop, clear the display and set the clipping region, the draw the scene. Before you update the display draw `cover_surf` in the clipping region:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    # clear screen and set clipping region
    screen.fill(0)    
    clip_rect = pygame.Rect(clip_center[0]-radius, clip_center[1]-radius, radius*2, radius*2)
    screen.set_clip(clip_rect)

    # draw the scene
    # [...]

    # draw transparent circle and update display
    screen.blit(cover_surf, clip_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ClipCircularRegion-2](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ClipCircularRegion-2#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

radius = 50
cover_surf = pygame.Surface((radius*2, radius*2))
cover_surf.fill(0)
cover_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
pygame.draw.circle(cover_surf, (255, 255, 255), (radius, radius), radius)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    clip_center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    # clear screen and set clipping region
    screen.fill(0)    
    clip_rect = pygame.Rect(clip_center[0]-radius, clip_center[1]-radius, radius*2, radius*2)
    screen.set_clip(clip_rect)

    # draw the scene
    for x in range(10):
        for y in range(10):
            color = (255, 255, 255) if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else (255, 0, 0)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x*50, y*50, 50, 50))

    # draw transparent circle and update display
    screen.blit(cover_surf, clip_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

If you want multiple circular drawing areas, then create a [`pygame.Surface.set_clip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_clip) with the same size as the display and set whit color key:

```py
cover_surf = pygame.Surface((400, 400))
cover_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
```

Fill the entire surface black and draw white circles on the surface:

```py
cover_surf.fill(0)
pygame.draw.circle(cover_surf, (255, 255, 255), (100, 100), 50)
pygame.draw.circle(cover_surf, (255, 255, 255), (300, 300), 70)
```

Blit the `cover_surf` on the window, before updating the display:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    # draw transparent circle and update display
    screen.blit(cover_surf, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ClipCircularRegion-3](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ClipCircularRegion-3#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

cover_surf = pygame.Surface((400, 400))
cover_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))

px = [100, 200, 300]
dx = [1, 2, 3] 

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # create cover surface
    cover_surf.fill(0)
    for i in range(3):
        radius = 40 + i*20
        pygame.draw.circle(cover_surf, (255, 255, 255), (px[i], 100+(i*100)), radius)
        px[i] += dx[i]
        if px[i] < radius or px[i] > 400 - radius:
            dx[i] = -dx[i]
        
    # draw the scene
    for x in range(10):
        for y in range(10):
            color = (255, 255, 255) if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else (255, 0, 0)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x*50, y*50, 50, 50))

    # draw transparent circle and update display
    screen.blit(cover_surf, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```