# how to make circular surface in pygame

Tags: pygame, transparency, crop, alpha, surface

I need to create a surface that has a bounding circle. Anything drawn on that surface should not be visible outside that bounding circle. I've tried using masks, subsurfaces, srcalpha, etc., but nothing seems to work.

My attempt:

```
w = ss.get_width  ()
h = ss.get_height ()    
    
TRANSPARENT = (255, 255, 255,   0)
OPAQUE      = (  0,   0,   0, 225)
    
crop = pygame.Surface ((w, h), pygame.SRCALPHA, ss)
crop.fill (TRANSPARENT)
    
c = round (w / 2), round (h / 2)
r = 1
pygame.gfxdraw.     aacircle (crop, *c, r, OPAQUE)
pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle (crop, *c, r, OPAQUE)
    
ss = crop.subsurface (crop.get_rect ())
App.set_subsurface (self, ss)
```

Later...

```
self.ss.fill (BLACK)
self.ss.blit (self.background, ORIGIN)
```

The background is a square image. It should be cropped into the shape of a circle and rendered on screen

Solution based on notes from Rabbid76:

```
def draw_scene (self, temp=None):
        if temp is None: temp = self.ss
        # 1. Draw everything on a surface with the same size as the window (background and scene).
        size = temp.get_size ()
        temp = pygame.Surface (size)
        self.draw_cropped_scene (temp)

        # 2. create the surface with the white circle.      
        self.cropped_background = pygame.Surface (size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.crop ()

        # 3. blit the former surface on the white circle.
        self.cropped_background.blit (temp, ORIGIN, special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MIN)
    
        # 4. blit the whole thing on the window.
        self.ss.blit (self.cropped_background, ORIGIN)

    def draw_cropped_scene (self, temp): App.draw_scene (self, temp)
```

An example implementation of crop() is:

```
def crop (self):
        o, bounds = self.bounds
        bounds = tr (bounds) # round elements of tuple
        pygame.gfxdraw.     aaellipse (self.cropped_background, *bounds, *bounds, OPAQUE)
        pygame.gfxdraw.filled_ellipse (self.cropped_background, *bounds, *bounds, OPAQUE)
```

Comment: no. I'm not seeing where that will cause opaque things to be opaque within the circle and transparent outside the circle.

Comment: how do I use a bounding box to do a circular crop of everything that's drawn on to the surface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The background is a square image. It should be cropped into the shape of a circle and rendered on screen

You can achieve this by using the blend mode `BLEND_RGBA_MIN` (see [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit)).

Create a transparent [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) with the same size as `self.background`. Draw a whit circle in the middle of the *Surface* and blend the background on this *Surface* using the blend mode `BLEND_RGBA_MIN`. Finally you can *blit* it on the screen:

```py
size = self.background.get_size()
self.cropped_background = pygame.Surface(size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.ellipse(self.cropped_background, (255, 255, 255, 255), (0, 0, *size))
self.cropped_background.blit(self.background, (0, 0), special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MIN)
```

```py
self.ss.fill(BLACK)
self.ss.blit(self.cropped_background, ORIGIN)
```

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ClipCircularRegion-1](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ClipCircularRegion-1#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((250, 250))

background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
        color = (255, 255, 255) if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else (255, 0, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(background, color, (x*50, y*50, 50, 50))

size = background.get_size()
cropped_background = pygame.Surface(size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.ellipse(cropped_background, (255, 255, 255, 255), (0, 0, *size))
cropped_background.blit(background, (0, 0), special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MIN)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        
    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(cropped_background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

See Also [How to fill only certain circular parts of the window in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657481/how-to-fill-only-certain-circular-parts-of-the-window-in-pygame)

Comment: I feel like we're getting warmer.
    size = ss.get_size()
    self.cropped_background = pygame.Surface(size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(self.cropped_background, (255, 255, 255, 255), (0, 0, *size))
  self.cropped_background.blit(ss, (0, 0),
    special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MIN)

However, calling App.set_subsurface (self, ss) causes no cropping to happen when set_background() is called later, and calling App.set_subsurface (self, cropped_background) causes nothing to be drawn when set_background() is called.

Comment: @user1456735 I have no idea what you want to say. We are not getting warmer, but you overcomplicate things. It is not possible that something is cropped when you _blit_ on the window. You have to do it the other way around. 1. Draw everything on a surface with the same size as the window (background and scene). 2. create the surface with the white circle. 3 _blit_ the former surface on the white circle. 4. _blit_ the whole thing on the window.

Comment: That clarified it. Thanks. Doing it the other way around worked.