# How do I modify this code to add a striped pattern to the star?

Tags: python, pygame

I have this script that creates a star in Pygame.

```py
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 400

DARK_BLUE  = (   3,   5,  54)
STARRY     = ( 230, 255, 80 )


### initialisation
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )
pygame.display.set_caption("Star")


# Define a star
centre_coord = ( WINDOW_WIDTH//2, WINDOW_HEIGHT//2 )
star_points  = [ (165, 151), (200, 20), (235, 151), (371, 144), (257, 219),
                 (306, 346), (200, 260), (94, 346), (143, 219), (29, 144)   ]

# Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Re-draw the window
    window.fill( DARK_BLUE )                             # background fill
    pygame.draw.polygon( window, STARRY, star_points )   # Draw the star
    pygame.display.flip()                                # Update the display

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Is there a way I can modify this to have a striped shape within the star. I've looked and I can't find many resourced to do this. I've tried this in both pygame and psychopy. I'm open to rewriting the entire script if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a striped image of the size of the star. You can arrange and color the strips as you like. For example:

```py
stripes = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
stripes.fill(STARRY)
offset_x = 400
for x in range(-offset_x, 400, 20):
    if (x//20) % 2 == 0:
        pts = [(x, 0), (x+20, 0), (x+20+offset_x, 400), (x+offset_x, 400)]
        pygame.draw.polygon(stripes, "red", pts)
```

After that you have to use the texture to draw the polygon. There are 2 ways to do this.

---

**Option 1**

You can use [`pygame.gfxdraw.textured_polygon()`](https://pyga.me/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html#pygame.gfxdraw.textured_polygon), which draws a textured polygon. Import the `pygame.gfxdraw` module:

```py
import pygame.gfxdraw
```

Finally draw the shape with [`pygame.gfxdraw.textured_polygon()`](https://pyga.me/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html#pygame.gfxdraw.textured_polygon):

```py
pygame.gfxdraw.textured_polygon(window, star_points, stripes, 0, 0)
```

---

**Option 2**

If you don't want to use the `gfxdraw` module you have to clip the image. Create a mask from the star points in the size of the image:

```py
mask_image = pygame.Surface(stripes.get_size(), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(mask_image, (255, 255, 255), star_points)
mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(mask_image)
```

Create a clipped striped image using the mask of the striped image. This is also explained in on one of my earlier answers: [How to free transform image in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69271298/how-to-free-transform-image-in-pygame/69272398#69272398).

```py
star_stripes = mask.to_surface(setsurface = stripes.convert_alpha(), unsetcolor = (0, 0, 0, 0))
```

---

Minimal examples of both solutions:

[image]

**Option 1**

```py
import pygame
import pygame.gfxdraw

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 400

DARK_BLUE  = (   3,   5,  54)
STARRY     = ( 230, 255, 80 )

### initialisation
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )
pygame.display.set_caption("Star")

# Define a star
centre_coord = ( WINDOW_WIDTH//2, WINDOW_HEIGHT//2 )
star_points  = [ (165, 151), (200, 20), (235, 151), (371, 144), (257, 219),
                 (306, 346), (200, 260), (94, 346), (143, 219), (29, 144)   ]

stripes = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
stripes.fill(STARRY)
offset_x = 400
for x in range(-offset_x, 400, 20):
    if (x//20) % 2 == 0:
        pts = [(x, 0), (x+20, 0), (x+20+offset_x, 400), (x+offset_x, 400)]
        pygame.draw.polygon(stripes, "red", pts)

# Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Re-draw the window
    window.fill( DARK_BLUE )                             # background fill
    pygame.gfxdraw.textured_polygon(window, star_points, stripes, 0, 0)
    pygame.display.flip()                                # Update the display

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

pygame.quit()
```

**Option 2**

```py
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 400

DARK_BLUE  = (   3,   5,  54)
STARRY     = ( 230, 255, 80 )

### initialisation
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )
pygame.display.set_caption("Star")

# Define a star
centre_coord = ( WINDOW_WIDTH//2, WINDOW_HEIGHT//2 )
star_points  = [ (165, 151), (200, 20), (235, 151), (371, 144), (257, 219),
                 (306, 346), (200, 260), (94, 346), (143, 219), (29, 144)   ]

stripes = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
stripes.fill(STARRY)
offset_x = 400
for x in range(-offset_x, 400, 20):
    if (x//20) % 2 == 0:
        pts = [(x, 0), (x+20, 0), (x+20+offset_x, 400), (x+offset_x, 400)]
        pygame.draw.polygon(stripes, "red", pts)

mask_image = pygame.Surface(stripes.get_size(), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(mask_image, (255, 255, 255), star_points)
mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(mask_image)
star_stripes = mask.to_surface(setsurface = stripes.convert_alpha(), unsetcolor = (0, 0, 0, 0))

# Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Re-draw the window
    window.fill( DARK_BLUE )                             # background fill
    window.blit(star_stripes, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()                                # Update the display

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: @3141592654 You can draw diagonal strips with `pygame.draw.polygon`. See the answer.

Comment: *"The other thing is that you could rotate the surface after drawing straight lines"*. No, you can't. The surface will not be filled with stripes on the corners, but with a uniform color (If you are talking about `pygame.transform.rotate`). Anyway, creating the stripes is not the main point of the question. The main point is to apply a pattern or texture only to a specific shape, but not to a rectangular area.

Comment: @3141592654 Use "Option 2" and `pygame.draw.circle(mask_image, (255, 255, 255), center, radius)` instead of `pygame.draw.polygon(mask_image, (255, 255, 255), star_points)`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64075338/how-to-make-circular-surface-in-pygame/64075812#64075812 and https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_clipping.md