# pygame: mask non-image type surfaces

Tags: python, pygame

I know how to mask images. But if I simply want to create a circle and mask it, it would be annoying to create an image of a simple circle outside of my code, especially when I need to create different kinds of circles. Appearantly you can create Rect objects in pygame but there is no class Circle.
`pygame.mask.from_surface` requires a `surface`. Can I pass a non-image type surface as a parameter? If so how can I mask circles and/or other objects?

Here's something I imagined which obviously throws an error:

```
circle = pygame.Circle((10, 10), 5) # (center coordinates), radius
pygame.mask.from_surface(circle)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create a circular mask directly. See [`pygame.mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html). You need to draw a circle on a *Surface*. Create a function that creates a *Surface* and draw a circle on the *Surface*:

```py
def circleSurface(color, radius):
    shape_surf = pygame.Surface((radius * 2, radius * 2), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.draw.circle(shape_surf, color, (radius, radius), radius)
    return shape_surf
```

Create the *Mask* from the *Surface*:

```py
circle = circleSurface((255, 255, 255), 5) # (center coordinates), radius
pygame.mask.from_surface(circle)
```

---

However, if you want to use a circle to clip an area of the display, see the answers to the following questions:

- [how to make circular surface in PyGame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64075338/how-to-make-circular-surface-in-pygame/64075812#64075812)
  [image: how to make circular surface in PyGame]
- [How to fill only certain circular parts of the window in PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657481/how-to-fill-only-certain-circular-parts-of-the-window-in-pygame/61658124#61658124/61658124#61658124)
  [image: How to fill only certain circular parts of the window in PyGame?]
  [image: How to fill only certain circular parts of the window in PyGame?]

Comment: I like the way you put the working demo along with the link.